# same data volume attached to multiple container even in different host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, flocker

I'm able to bind a docker volume to a specific container in a swarm thanks to [flocker](https://flocker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but now i would have multiple replicas of my server  (to do load balancing) and so i'm searching something to bind the same data volume to multiple replicas of a docker service.
In flocker documentaiton i have found that

> Can more than one container access the same volume? Flocker works by
>   creating a 1 to 1 relationship of a volume and a container. This means
>   you can have multiple volumes for one container, and those volumes
>   will always follow that container.
>
> Flocker attaches volumes to the individual agent host (docker host)
>   and this can only be one host at a time because Flocker attaches
>   Block-based storage. Nodes on different hosts cannot access the same
>   volume, because it can only be attached to one node at a time.
>
> If multiple containers on the same host want to use the same volume,
>   they can, but be careful because multiple containers accessing the
>   same storage volume can cause corruption.
>
> Can I attach a single volume to multiple hosts? Not currently, support
>   from multi-attach backends like GCE in Read Only mode, or NFS-like
>   backends like storage, or distributed filesystems like GlusterFS would
>   need to be integrated. Flocker focuses mainly on block-storage uses
>   cases that attach a volume to a single node at a time.

So i think is no possible to do what i want with flocker.
I could use a different orchestrator (k8s) if that could help me, even if i have no experience with that.

I would not use NAS/NFS or anything distribuited filesystems.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In k8s, you can mount volume to different Pods at the same time if technology that backs the volume supports shared access.

As mentioned in [Kubernetes Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/):

> Access Modes A PersistentVolume can be mounted on a host in any way
>   supported by the resource provider. As shown below, providers will
>   have different capabilities and each PV’s access modes are set to the
>   specific modes supported by that particular volume. For example, NFS
>   can support multiple read/write clients, but a specific NFS PV might
>   be exported on the server as read-only. Each PV gets its own set of
>   access modes describing that specific PV’s capabilities.
>
> The access modes are:
>
> - ReadWriteOnce – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
> - ReadOnlyMany – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
> - ReadWriteMany – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

Types of volumes that supports ReadOnlyMany mode:

- AzureFile
- CephFS
- FC
- FlexVolume
- GCEPersistentDisk
- Glusterfs
- iSCSI
- Quobyte
- NFS
- RBD
- ScaleIO

Types of volumes that supports ReadWriteMany mode:

- AzureFile
- CephFS
- Glusterfs
- Quobyte
- RBD
- PortworxVolume
- VsphereVolume(works when pods are collocated)